# ExpandableListView - RadioButton losing state

Tags: android, expandablelistview, checked

I have ExpandableListView with SimpleExpandableListAdapter.
I have set CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE. Set checked works using setchecked in onitemclicked. My problem is - when expand/colapse group - checked state dissapear. Tried to solve this keeping checked state using boolean array in adapter and setting checked in getchildview. It doesn't solve problem.

Comment: are you providing your own layout for row?

Comment: Yes. At firs I blame my layout. Tried with standard android layout for this case. Result is the same. custom layout is for colors and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution for moment is to set multi choice mode and keep only 1 cheched item in adapter.Now expand colapse doesn't make checked state go.